# Various issues with siunitx's option exponent-to-prefix

Tags: siunitx

I am using this to collect some of my thoughts on the use of `exponent-to-prefix` because I know the developer is around here. My question could be titled "Will those three things be fixed in a future version of `siunitx`?" I could submit this as a bug report, but I imagine not all of this may be fixed, so the answer might include why. I am also looking for a short-term workaround to the final example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    % infinite loop:
    %\SIlist[exponent-to-prefix=true]{1e3}{m}

    % should maybe print a warning, not an error:
    % \SIlist[scientific-notation=true,exponent-to-prefix=true]{10000; 20000}{\m}

    % this works as expected:
    \SIlist[scientific-notation=engineering,exponent-to-prefix=true]{10000; 20000}{\m}

    % does not work as expected. **Edit** I would love to see "10.000 and 20.000 km" here:
    \SIlist[scientific-notation=engineering,exponent-to-prefix=true,list-units=single]{10000; 20000}{\m}

    % this is closer, but still does not work:
    \SIlist[scientific-notation=fixed,fixed-exponent=3,exponent-to-prefix=true,list-units=single]{10000; 20000}{\m}
\end{document}
```

The first line causes an infinite loop that should not happen so easily, I would think.

The second line throws an error, but it should really be a warning in my opinion because the manual clearly states

> When the exponent-to-prefix option is set true, the package will **attempt** to
>   convert any exponents in quantities into unit prefixes, and will attach these to the first
>   unit given. *This process is only possible if the exponent is one for which a prefix is
>   available, and retains the number of significant figures in the input.*

So in my eyes, a warning would be enough.

Finally, I wonder how (with a patch or a future version), `exponent-to-prefix` can be combined with `list-units=single` successfully.

Comment: You can ask Joseph Wright in TeX.SX chat. He is there 'sometimes' ;-)

Comment: All the examples for `exponent-to-prefix` use a “macro form” for the unit.

Answer (score 1):

Partial response for the first point only: using `\meter` instead of `m` in unit seems to fix the infinite loop (but I cannot explain why).

```
\SIlist[exponent-to-prefix=true]{1e3;2e3}{\metre}
% Produces "1 km and 2 km"
```